# How to use UTF-8 character in URL

Tags: php, url, encoding

I read some questions on this, they use `rawurlencode` or `percent encoding` to encode utf-8 characters but I find some different examples like this: `xn--pbt1by64f.lofter.com` and `http://xn--wgv71a.com/`, this will also be converted to utf-8 string in browser address bar(e.g.`温家宝.lofter.com`,`日本.com`). This is obviously not percent encoding or simply `urlencode` result, what's this encoding method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [Internationalized domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

And check php's [IDN Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.idn.php)

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Punycode":

> In computing, Punycode is an instance of a general encoding syntax
>   (Bootstring) by which a string of Unicode characters is transformed
>   uniquely and reversibly into a smaller, restricted character set.
>
> Punycode is intended for the encoding of labels in the
>   Internationalized Domain Names in Applications (IDNA) framework, such
>   that these domain names may be represented in the ASCII character set
>   allowed in the Domain Name System of the Internet. The encoding syntax
>   is defined in IETF document RFC 3492.[1]

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode